# Prolog dependencies: include vs ensure_loaded

Tags: prolog

I'm writing a program in prolog. I have 3 files: Class.pl, main.pl, utilities.pl.

Class.pl:

```
:- include('utilities.pl').
```

main.pl:

```
:- include('utilities.pl').
:- include('Class.pl').
```

When I compile main.pl I get the warning "clauses for ... are not together".

However, if I switch include with ensure_loaded, it doesn't give me a warning anymore. I'm assuming this has to do with circular dependencies and the predicates in utilities.pl being rewritten? Does ensure_loaded work like #pragma once in C++?

But I've also read somewhere that include actually includes the code, while ensure_loaded only consults it?

If anyone could clear things up for me and let me know what I should be doing, I'd be very grateful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly, a directive `include/1` means `#include` and `ensure_loaded/1` means `#include` with an include guard. Thus `#include-once`. Well, roughly.

You get the warning because `utilities.pl` is included twice.

Here are the relevant parts from the standard ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995:

> #### 7.4.2.7 `include/1`
>
> If `F` is an implementation defined ground term designating
>  a
>   Prolog text unit, then Prolog text *P1* which contains
>  a directive
>   `include(F)` is identical to a Prolog text *P2*
>  obtained by
>   replacing the directive `include(F)` in *P1* by
>  the Prolog text
>   denoted by `F`.

Whereas

> #### 7.4.2.8 `ensure_loaded/1`
>
> ...
>
> When multiple directives `ensure_loaded(P_text)` exist
>  for the same
>   Prolog text, that Prolog text is included in
>  the Prolog text
>   prepared for execution only once. The
>  position where it is
>   included is implementation defined.

Current Prolog systems require that the included text is a valid Prolog text. So it does not leave open any clause or `/*`-comments.  The text inclusion is thus not taken completely literally.